# Swipe to open react native navigation drawer

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I am attempting to set up a react native navigation drawer and I have a button that toggles the drawer correctly although I am trying to set up the swipe function to also open the drawer, and this does not work at all. My drawer.js file is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import HomeStack from './homeStack';
import AboutStack from './aboutStack';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const AppNavigator = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
            <Drawer.Screen
                name='Home'
                component={HomeStack}
            />
            <Drawer.Screen
                name='About'
                component={AboutStack}
            />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

Its imported to my App.js like this

```
import React from 'react';

import Navigator from './routes/drawer';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Navigator />
    )
}
```

I've already tried the suggestion in [this post](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7536#issuecomment-540667009) but have had no success.

I am running react native 0.63, react native navigation 5.9, react native navigation drawer 5.12.3 and react native gesture handler 1.10.0

For reference here is my index.js file with the updates in the previously mentioned post

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

Comment: what not work, swipe or drawer?

Comment: The swipe function

Comment: where is it?
``AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));``

Comment: As said, I have tried that suggestion and it did not work

Comment: I put that in the index.js file as the comment suggested